# Query multiple many-to-many relationship with linq c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, many-to-many

I have three tables in my database Game, Role and Player. Between Game and Role I have a many to many relationship and between Role and Player. I also have a one to many relationship between Game and Player. I have used Entity Framework to map my tables.
What I am trying to achieve is to get all the players under specific gameID and roleID.

```
    public IList<Game> GetGamesRolePlayer(int? gameID, int? roleID)
    {

        using (DbContextdb = new DbContext())
        {
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

            if (gameID.HasValue && !roleID.HasValue)
            {
                var query1 = (from g in db.Game.Include(r => r.Role)
                              where g.ID == gameID
                              select g).ToList();
                _games = query1;
                return _games;

            }
            if (gameID.HasValue && roleID.HasValue)
            {
                var query2 = (from g in db.Game
                              from r in db.Role.Include(p => p.Player)
                              where g.ID == game && r.ID == roleID
                              select g).ToList();
                _games = query2;
                return _games;
            }
            var query = from game in db.Game select game;
            _games = query.Include(r => r.Role).ToList();
            return _games;
        }
    }
```

Comment: you need the players or games?

Comment: int can't be null...

Comment: I am having optional parameters and this the only way I could make it work :)

Comment: If you make the int nullable though, like int?, it can be null. Of course that probably brings about other changes.

Comment: Please could you clarify what is the issue and what are you trying to achieve, your explanation and code are telling us two different things

Comment: Well, I am trying to get the games, and then if there is a value in gameID, only get the specific games with their roles and then if there is value under gameid and roleid get all the players under that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I though you need the players but your code is telling another thing. If you need the games,you can build the following query using navigation properties:

```
using (DbContextdb = new DbContext())
{
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        IQueryable<Game> query=db.Game.Include(g=>g.Roles);

        if (gameID.HasValue)
           query=query.Where(g=>g.ID==gameID.Value)

        if (roleID.HasValue)
           query=query.Include(g=>g.Roles.Select(r=>r.Players))
                      .Where(g=>g.Roles.Any(r=>r.ID==roleID.Value))

        return query.ToList();
}
```